# Spring 3.2.4 + Tiles 3 = infinite loop when resolving view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, stack-overflow, tiles, tiles-3

I'm trying to use Spring MVC 3.2.4 & Tiles 3.0.1 with Regexp prefixes in my tiles.xml file.  I'm a newbie with Tiles, so I might be doing something wrong, but have been trying to follow things I have read on in the Tiles doc site as well as apply stuff from the tech.finn.no blog.

Unfortunately, when I use completeAutoLoad=true with RegExp prefix in my tiles.xml file, I get stuck in an infinite loop when trying to resolve the view.

Stack Trace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)

....
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.encodeURL(SaveContextOnUpdateOrErrorResponseWrapper.java:181)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)

....
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.encodeURL(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag.createUrl(UrlTag.java:227)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.UrlTag.doEndTag(UrlTag.java:174)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.webutil.load_002dscripts_tag._jspx_meth_spring_005furl_005f0(load_002dscripts_tag.java:300)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.webutil.load_002dscripts_tag.doTag(load_002dscripts_tag.java:113)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.layouts.default_jsp._jspx_meth_util_005fload_002dscripts_005f0(default_jsp.java:176)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tiles.layouts.default_jsp._jspService(default_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

webmvc-config.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext" autowire="constructor" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" >
    <property name="cache" value="false"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
<property name="completeAutoload" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Tiles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="REGEXP:(.+)" template="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/layouts/default.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="meta" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/meta.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="head" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/head.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/body.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/tiles/{1}/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

default.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%> 
<%@ taglib prefix="util" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/util"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />  
    <jsp:directive.page pageEncoding="UTF-8" /> 

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />    
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="meta" ignore="true" />

        <util:load-scripts />

        <tiles:insertAttribute name="head" ignore="true" />

        <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name" htmlEscape="false"/>
        <title><spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" /></title>
    </head>

    <body class="tundra spring">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="true" /></div>
            <div id="menu"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" ignore="true" /></div>   
            <div id="main">
                <div id="body"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/></div> 
                <div id="footer"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" ignore="true"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/WEB-INF/views/tiles/secure/login/body.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="util" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/util"%>

<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />

<div class="container">

<form name="login" class="form-signin" action='<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check"/>' method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="j_username" placeholder="Email address" autofocus> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="j_password" placeholder="Password"> 
    <label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me</label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
</div>
```

I don't think there is anything specifically special in this configuration, so am not sure why I get into an infinite loop.  If I replace the CompleteAutoTilesInitializer class with the BasicTilesInitializerClass and use Wildcards (ie: */*) instead and replace {1} with {1}/{2}, then the view loads properly (no infinite loop).

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or is this a Tiles problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a similar SO issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617343/827480) that pointed out that the regexp is too greedy and tries to match all attributes as well forever, hence causing the StackOverflow.  Work around at the moment is to use a less greedy regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some traction under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TILES-572 and http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.tiles.user/612